# MissingListField when assign struct literal to node

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm trying to create a k8s node struct and assign default value to it.

The following code complains "*unknown field Name in struct literal*"

```
node = &corev1.Node{Name: pod.Spec.NodeName}
```

However, this code is fine:

```
node = &corev1.Node{}
node.Name = pod.Spec.NodeName
```

why?

Comment: Field doesn't exists in Node or not exported (not starting  in capital letter).This is what i can tell from above ,provide more reference to help you better

Comment: @dave's answer provides the context. The node is a k8s Node.

Answer (score 1):

If the second code works, I'd assume there is an embedded struct, and looking at the code (assuming it's [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/core/v1/types.go#L5558-L5576)) that appears to be the case:

```
type Node struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    // Standard object's metadata.
    // More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#metadata
    // +optional
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=metadata"`

    // Spec defines the behavior of a node.
    // https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#spec-and-status
    // +optional
    Spec NodeSpec `json:"spec,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=spec"`

    // Most recently observed status of the node.
    // Populated by the system.
    // Read-only.
    // More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#spec-and-status
    // +optional
    Status NodeStatus `json:"status,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=status"`
}
```

So the name field is likely either part of `metav1.TypeMeta`, or `metav1.ObjectMeta`, digging [deeper](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#ObjectMeta) it's on ObjectMeta, which means to define inline, you'll need to do something like:

package main

```
import (
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

// ...

node := &corev1.Node{ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{ Name: pod.Spec.NodeName}}
```

Comment: Thanks @dave for your answer! 
since `Name` field can be promoted to struct Node, why doesn't the promotion apply to the struct literal?